# Dump images from unmanaged image list to disk

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, unmanaged

I'm porting a C++ SDK from a USB device to use in C# through pinvoke and and I'm having good progress so far, and the problem now is with a function that builds an image list that I can use to attach to other controls using functions like [SetImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y355zfta%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

What I would like to do is save all the images from this list to the disk and use them later.

There are other functions that returns the index of a paraticular image inside this list, so I could pass this index and then save the image to the disk.

Comment: I don't understand the actual problem. If the SDK function gives you the list correctly, why can't you save the images yourself?

Comment: it gives me a pointer to the list to use with other controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [`CImageList` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xc4z2c7.aspx) instance (which you get by calling to the [`Detach` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b75edw6k.aspx) on the [`GetImageList` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hc0d17x3.aspx) on the [`CListCtrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx) instance that you have), you can get the `HIMAGELIST` handle by calling the [Detach method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b75edw6k.aspx).

From there you can call the underlying Windows API through the [Platform Invocation Services (P/Invoke) layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx).

The following assumes you have this `HIMAGELIST` pointer in an [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx):

```
IntPtr imageList = ...;
```

First, you'll need to declare the [`ImageList_GetImageCount` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761552.aspx) in .NET:

```
[DllImport("Comctl32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int ImageList_GetImageCount(IntPtr himl);
```

And of course, store the result of that call in a variable:

```
int imageCount = ImageList_GetImageCount(imageList);
```

You'll also need to be able to get the details about each image, so you'll need the call to [`ImageList_GetImageInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761554.aspx):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct RECT
{
    public int left, top, right, bottom;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct IMAGEINFO
{
    public IntPtr hbmImage;
    public IntPtr hbmMask;
    public int Unused1;
    public int Unused2;
    public RECT rcImage;
}

[DllImport("Comctl32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ImageList_GetImageInfo(IntPtr himl, int i,
    ref IMAGEINFO pImageInfo);
```

With these, you can start your loop to get the information about the image:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; ++i)
{
    // The image info.
    var imageInfo = new IMAGEINFO();

    // Get the call to ImageList_GetImageInfo.
    if (!ImageList_GetImageInfo(imageList, i, ref imageInfo)
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
```

Notice that in the [`IMAGEINFO` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761393.aspx) has a field that contains the pointer to the bitmap (the `hbmImage` field).

This is a handle to an [`HBITMAP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handle, which has an equivalent in .NET in the [`Bitmap` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx).  You can translate between the two by calling the static [`FromHbitmap` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k061we7x.aspx) on the [`Image` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84767bxk.aspx) (yes, it's strange it's not on the `Bitmap` class):

```
    using (Bitmap bitmap = Image.FromHbitmap(imageInfo.hbmImage))
    {
```

Once you have the `Bitmap` instance, you can call the [`Save` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save.aspx) on each instance to dump them to disk:

```
        bitmap.Save("<need to generate a filename>.<and extension>");
    }
}
```

Note that there is the [`ImageList` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx) in .NET, but there's no way to pass the `HIMAGELIST` handle to the managed implementation (which would have made this much easier).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it IS possible to create  a managed ImageList from an HIMAGELIST handle.
I tested this 2 min. ago:

```
Public Shared Function ImageList_FromHIMAGELIST(cxcy As Integer, uFlags As UInteger, initSize As Integer, growSize As Integer, _
                                         hicons() As IntPtr) As ImageList

    Dim himl = ImageList_Create(cxcy, cxcy, uFlags, initSize, growSize)
    If Not IsNothing(hicons) AndAlso hicons.Length > 0 Then
        For Each HIcon As IntPtr In hicons
            ImageList_ReplaceIcon(himl, -1, HIcon)
        Next
    End If
    Dim NativeILType As Type = _
        GetType(Button).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.ImageList+NativeImageList", False, True)
    If IsNothing(NativeILType) Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Dim natObj As Object = _
            Activator.CreateInstance( _
                NativeILType, BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic, Nothing, {himl}, Nothing)


        If Not IsNothing(natObj) Then
            Dim iml As New ImageList With {.ImageSize = New Size(cxcy, cxcy)}
            iml.GetType.InvokeMember("nativeImageList", _
                                     BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.SetField, _
                                      Nothing, iml, {natObj})
            Return iml
        End If
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```